# Getting com.xero.api.XeroApiException: Unauthorized error when trying to create/update invoices

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I'm using [Xero-Java](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java) and I'm trying to push invoices to Xero. The scopes I requested in the Ouath2 authorization were:

```
openid
email
profile
offline_access
accounting.settings
accounting.transactions
accounting.contacts
accounting.journals.read
accounting.reports.read
accounting.attachments
```

Invoking the AccountingApi.updateInvoice() method throws the error:

```
com.xero.api.XeroApiException: Unauthorized - check your scopes and confirm access to this resource
```

I was under the impression that the scope accounting.transactions would allow pushing Invoices to Xero. Where is my problem and how do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey George, what's your clientId, I'll look up some logs on our side and see if I can spot the issue

Comment: Hi @MJMortimer, Any way I can send you this info privately?

Comment: ClientIds aren't considered sensitive (they're included in the Authorization url for anyone to see for example) - clientSecret should never be shared). Although if you'd prefer, you can raise a ticket with our support team to include this information here: https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/

Comment: Hi @MJMortimer. Here is my clientId FF55718478944B34A5BC26FD7AD720E8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at some logs, it seems that your access token has expired. Access tokens only live for 30 minutes.

As you've used offline_access, you can acquire a new access token for the same user by using the refresh token provided during user authorisation with a refresh request as outlined in the Readme of the SDKs github repo.

You'll probably want to check token expiration prior to each call to the Xero API.

Comment: Thanks @MJMortimer. That was probably the issue. However I am now getting the non descriptive error XeroApiException: Bad Request on all push attempts. Is there a way to get detailed error messages to find out what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: There should be some details in the bad request response. There's a detailed example of how to handle exceptions in the Readme that should help you